# Github error "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind"

Tags: git, github, repository

Im trying to init a new project in github
These are my steps that lead to this error:

Create a new repository in github, copy link `https://github.com/username/repository.git`

`>cd to project folder`

`>git init`

`>git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repository.git`

`>git add -A`

`>git status`

`>git commit -m "adding files"`

`>git push origin master`

Error:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/repository.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried to do a `>git pull` but I am getting a different error

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
```

Next I tried the suggestion above

```
>git pull origin master
From https://github.com/username/repository.git
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I found a solution online, which is a fix, but it doesn't tell me what I did wrong in the sequence of git commands

`>git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get refuse to merge error when I run "git pull origin master"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272175/get-refuse-to-merge-error-when-i-run-git-pull-origin-master)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+fatal%3A+refusing+to+merge+unrelated+histories

Comment: When you created a new repository at Github you created it non-empty — you added a license or a README. Those files were committed to the repository thus producing a history unrelated to your local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> git init

That was what you did wrong. You should've cloned the repo from github.

---

To elaborate. You started a new repository on github

> Create a new repository in github, copy link https://github.com/username/repository.git

Think of this as the same as being SSH'd into github.com and doing `git init`. This initializes i.e. creates the first commit on master for a blank repo.

Then. Locally, you also did `git init`.

This initialized a new local repo with a commit on master.

At this stage you have 2 *different* repo's (one local / one remote), and although the hashes for the blobs would be the same (assuming both repo's are empty), the tree structures and refs could be different. Meaning the initial commit hashes are different. This is my guess as to why you got the error:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref.
```

It's also the reason why pulling wouldn't do anything. Pulling is just a fetch / merge operation combined.

But if you consider your scenario, even if you pulled before you added files and committed locally it's still 2 repo's (local / remote) with potentially different commit hashes on the initial commit... the one you initialized locally on your machine thinks it's commit hash is correct. The one you initialized on github thinks it's commit has is correct.